# como hacer una búsqueda filtrada mediante ComboBox

Tags: c#

Necesito que un formulario de clientes que tengo el usuario pueda realizar la búsqueda de clientes mediante la digitacion de datos en un textbox el cual va a tener la información filtrada mediante un ComboBox. OSEA me doy a entender con un ejemplo :

si quiero buscar por nombres selecciono en el ComboBox Nombre y puede proceder a buscar por nombres en el textbox...

lenguaje c# y sql
nombre de la tabla: tbclientes
campos de la tabla: 
ID_clientes int 
Nombres varchar(50) 
Direccion varchar(200)
[E-mail] varchar(50)
Telefono varchar(50)

¿alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Que tipo de base de datos estas usando?

Comment: sql managment studio

Comment: ¿Usar LINQ no es una opción?

Comment: no, no me lo permiten...debe de ser c# y sql managment studio

Comment: Puedes usar LINQ + EntityFramework en C# y SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que deberías hacer lo siguiente:

1. Crear el form de la búsqueda con tus controles, en el ejemplo cree el cmbBuscarPor que es un combo con los nombres de los campos de la tabla y txtBuscar que es el text donde deberás poner la búsqueda.
2. Llenar el combo con los campos de tu tabla, ya sea por código o en vista de diseño.
3. En el botón buscar debes incluir el siguiente código:

   ```
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source = ServidorDB; initial catalog = DataBase; user id = Usuario; password = Password"))
   {
           conn.Open();
           string query = "select * from tbclientes where  " + cmbBuscarPor.Text + " = @param1";
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", txtBuscar.Text);
           SqlDataReader resultado = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   }
   ```

Comment: gracias me ayudo mucho tu codigo..

Comment: Excelente! Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Web, escritorio?? Tienes el SP que filtra?

Yo hago esto en web:

## Controller:

```
public JsonResult ListarEmpresa(string term){
            var listaEmpresa = logicEmpresa.listarEmpresas(term).Select(e => new { value = e.ID_EMPRESA, label = e.NOM_EMPRESA });
            return Json(listaEmpresa, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Previo SP y DLL. Esto me ayuda con un efecto algo asi como cuando buscamos en google.

Comment: escritorio.. sp??

Comment: Smc no puedo hacerlo en web el proyecto ha de ser de escritorio es un proyecto de la universidad

Comment: El SP

create prodecure SelListaClientes
Nombres varchar(50)
as
 select *
 from tbclientes
 where Nombres like Nombres
go

Comment: ese es un procedimiento almacenado para crearlo en mi base de datos?

Comment: Si, luego tienes que entrar al visual studio, generar un dataContext, crear una conex referenciar las tablas o en este caso el SP (que realizaste en el SQL) y luego crear la clase con algo como 
public static List<SelListaClientesResult> SelListaClientes(string sNombre = "")
        {
            using (var oData = new ClienteDataContext())
            {
                var oLista = oData.SelListaClientes(sNombre).ToList();
                return oLista;
            }
        }